# How to compare two rows of same entry in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, comparison, aggregate-functions

Below is my query which I am running against Postgres database.

```
select distinct(col1),col2,col3,col4 
    from tableNot 
    where col5 = 100 and col6 = '78' 
    order by col4 DESC  limit 100;
```

And below is the output I am getting back on the console-

```
col1            col2       col3      col4 

entry.one       1.2.3       18       subject
entry.one       1.2.8       18       newSubject
entry.two       3.4.9       20       lifePerfect
entry.two       3.4.5       17       helloPartner
```

- Now if you see my above output, `entry.one` and `entry.two` is coming twice so I would compare `col2` value for `entry.one` and whichever is higher, I will keep that row. So for `entry.one` I would compare `1.2.3` with `1.2.8` and `1.2.8` is higher for `entry.one` so I would keep this row only for `entry.one`.
- Similarly with `entry.two`, I would compare `3.4.9` with `3.4.5` and `3.4.9` is higher for `entry.two` so I would keep this row only for `entry.two`.

And below is the output I would like to see on the console -

```
col1            col2       col3      col4 

entry.one       1.2.8       18       newSubject
entry.two       3.4.9       20       lifePerfect
```

Is this possible to do in SQL?

P.S Any Fiddle example would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for `distinct on` which is a Postgres specific extension to the `distinct` operator.

```
select distinct on (col1)  col1, col2, col3, col4 
from tableNot 
where col5 = 100 
  and col6 = '78' 
order by col1, col4 DESC  
limit 100;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/04698/1

---

Please note that `distinct` is **not** a function. `select distinct (col1), col2, col3` is exactly the same thing as `select distinct col1, col2, col3`.

The (standard SQL) `distinct` operator always operates on *all* columns of the select list, not just one.

The difference between `select distinct (col1), col2` and `select distinct col1, col2` is the same as the difference between `select (col1), col2` and `select col1, col2`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(select distinct(col1),col2,col3,col4 from tableNot 
where col5 = 100 and col6 = '78' order by col4 DESC  limit 100)t1
WHERE t1.col2 = (SELECT MAX(t2.col2) FROM (select distinct(col1),col2,col3,col4 
from tableNot 
where col5 = 100 and col6 = '78' order by col4 DESC  limit 100)t2 
WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col1 group by t2.col1)
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/47c3b/2)

Comment: Thanks Hamidreza, I am getting the following error after running your query: `ERROR:  argument of AND must be type boolean, not type integer
LINE 2: ...t1.col6 = '91' order by t1.col4 DESC  limit 100
                                                                     ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: argument of AND must be type boolean, not type integer
SQL state: 42804
Character: 181`

Comment: You are welcome my friend.my query just give you some clues.because i can't see your real table.tack a look at my query in `sql fiddle`,it will be so helpful for you to find the result.

Comment: I edit my query my friend and it is based on your query and if your query returns value,my query will returns value too.

Comment: At the end of your query, you have `group by t2.col)` here what does col mean? Is it col2 or col3?

Comment: you are right my friend, that is my fault and i edit it now it is `group by col1`

Comment: Somehow it's not working for me.. And I can still see entry.one showing twice and entry.two as well.. :( Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can try another simple query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, t1.col4 
FROM tableNot t1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(col2) col2 
FROM tableNot GROUP BY col1) t2  ON t1.col2=t2.col2
WHERE col5 = 100 AND col6 = '78' ORDER BY col4 DESC  LIMIT 100;
```